# Export excel worksheet to a text file

Tags: excel, output, text-files, vba

I would like to know the simplest way to create a text file and then write ALL the data from a worksheet into that file (tab-delimited). I don't only want to write particular cells into the sheet (I want everything on the worksheet) but also don't want to have to have to write every cell. I know the command for writing cells is like this:

open "c:|OUTPUT.txt" for output as #1
    print #1, cells(1,2) & cells(2,2) & cells(3,2) ...
close

but is there a way to just write all the data from the sheet into a txt file? I want to run this on a loop for many worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use the VBA `SaveAs` method to save it as a .txt by passing `xlTextWindows` as the FileFormat.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) for details on the `SaveAs` method.